# How to add attributes to a <textarea> using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

```
editElement.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    textComment.setAttribute("disabled", true)
    textComment.classList.add("uwu")
})
```

I am trying to add some attributes to my `<textarea>` from .js but I cannot make it work

Comment: `disabled` not `disable`. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8sbnyvq0/

Comment: i seen that and i correct that, but that not fix my question. thanks you anyways

Comment: @JuanMeow See my fiddle. It fixes the issue and works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code with a function instead of adding an eventlistener works.

```
function handleClick() {
  const demoTextArea = document.querySelector('#demo');
  demoTextArea.setAttribute('disabled', true);
  console.log(demoTextArea);
}
```

```
    <div>
      <button onclick="handleClick()">disable input</button>
    </div>

    <textarea id="demo">  demo  </textarea>
```

Here is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-uh2jzy?file=script.js)